# Can I change the style of a QObject by changing the ObjectName via stylesheets?

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets, qtwidgets

I recently learned about the nice possibility to style objects in Qt with a stylesheet. Now I want to change the background color of a QFrame after a specific event happened. So I set up two entries:

```css
QFrame#ColorA {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

QFrame#ColorB {
    background-color: #B2D235;
}
```

and gave the QFrame the ObjectName `ColorA` and it gets displayed perfectly fine. But when said event happens, and I set the ObjectName to `ColorB`, nothing in the UI changes.

I know that I can change the color by setting the stylesheet to `background-color: #B2D235`, but I thought there must be a nicer way through the stylesheet.

Comment: While not technically wrong or forbidden, changing the object name to alter the appearance is conceptually inopportune. A more appropriate solution would use the [property selector](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types), possibly with a custom Qt property if the widget doesn't have one that could be reflected by its state change. You'd still need to unpolish/polish, but at least it would be a more correct approach. Note that if the target is a container or complex widget (QScrollArea, QComboBox, etc), you should avoid defining generic properties, and always use selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the style modification to take effect, you have to call [unpolish()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstyle.html#unpolish)/[polish()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstyle.html#polish).

So when your event happens, add something like (if you call it directly from QFrame subclass)

```
style()->unpolish(this);
style()->polish(this);
```

or like this

```
style()->unpolish(ui->your_frame);
style()->polish(ui->your_frame);
```

if you call it from a class that contains your QFrame (I suppose that your QFrame is defined in a UI file).